# How to make a grid where each attribute is a textview underneath another textview

Tags: java, android, gridview, textview

I'm trying to create a 4*n grid where each attribute within the grid has a textView saying "1" then directly underneath that text view saying "One"

e.g.
[image: example image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="One"
    android:textSize="32sp" />
</GridLayout>
```

This just provides each text view next to each other in a grid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Create Recyclerview Grid it solve your problem...

Answer (score 2):

you should create your row layout file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="1"
android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="One"
android:textSize="32sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

inflate this row file in the adapter and set the not of items in each row for grid to 4.

one suggestion - user recyclerview with GridLayoutManager instead of GridLayout.